# PHP: Change XML element type (perhaps) and test children

Tags: php, xml

I have a situation where i have no control on the delivered XML format, but i need certain child elements of a specific parent to always be 3.

The problem is that the parent element type isn't unique, so i thought it would be an approach to change the element type, then loop through the children, count the results and fill these with empty values so the amount of children will always be 3.

I'm not such a php hero so some part of this approach makes sense to me, while i also have something in the back of my head that says this approach is out of control. Especially when the feed can have up to a few 1000 products.

What i eventually want is count the child elements of a certain parent, and if these are below a certain number (say 3), add child elements to the parent until the amount of child elements is 3.

The XML i'm provided with looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generated on 09/29/15 at 12:06:15 (http://pf.tradetracker.net) -->
<products>
    <product ID="1">
        <name>Name</name>
        [random other fields..]
        <properties>
            <property name="country">
                <value>Country</value>
            </property>
            <property name="region">
                <value>Region info 1</value>
                <value>Region info 2</value>
                <value>Region info 3</value>
            </property>
            [more property fields..]
        </properties>
    </product>
    [more products..]
</products>
```

And then of course with multiple products and properties.

For the processing of the feed it is important that the property with the *name* `region` *always* has three values. In some cases there are only one or two values provided. In these situations i need to add empty values until there are three again.

For the last part of the problem i can do something like

```
$xml_src = 'feed.xml'; 
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_src);
$output = '';
foreach($xml->product as $product){
    $i = 0;
    foreach($product->properties as $property){
        foreach($property->region as $region){
            foreach($region->children() as $child) {
                $i++;
                $children = count($region->children());
                if($children == 1){
                    $output .= '<value>'.$child.'</value><value></value><value></value>';
                }else if($children == 2){
                    $output .= '<value>'.$child.'</value><value></value>';
                }else if($children == 3){
                    $output .= '<value>'.$child.'</value>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then update (somehow) the values of the the property with the name `region`. I only have to find out how to do that..

As you can see i'm pretty stuck with this issue so anybody that can point me in the right direction makes me the happiest man of the day :)

**SOLUTION (and new 'problem')**
The solution posted works perfectly, even so good i stumble upon a new problem with the feed. For the import i need the three child elements of region to be numbered, like so:

```
<property name="region">
    <value1>Region info 1</value1>
    <value2>Region info 2</value2>
    <value3>Region info 3</value3>
</property>
```

The problem is that i can't find any method to edit existing nodes. Is that even possible or am i lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the `region` `property` elements that have less then 3 `value` children directly with Xpath. After that subtract the children count from 3 and you get how many value nodes you need to add. Use a simple loop to add the nodes.

```
$root = simplexml_load_file($xml_src);

$regions = $root->xpath('//property[@name = "region" and count(value) < 3]');
foreach ($regions as $region) {
  $difference = 3 - count($region->xpath('value'));
  for ($i = $difference; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $region->addChild('value');
  }
}

echo $root->asXml();
```

I prefer using DOM, but the logic is basically the same:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($xml_src);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$regions = $xpath->evaluate('//property[@name = "region" and count(value) < 3]');
foreach ($regions as $region) {
  $difference = 3 - $xpath->evaluate('count(value)', $region);
  for ($i = $difference; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $region->appendChild($document->createElement('value'));
  }
}

echo $document->saveXml();
```

### The Xpath

- `//property` - fetch any `property` element node
- `//property[@name = "region"]` - ... with a `name` attribute that is `region`
- `//property[count(value) < 3]` - ... that has less than 3 `value` children

`count(value)` as direct expression works with `DOMXpath::evaluate()`, because the method can return scalar values or node lists depending on the expression. `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` can only return nodes as array of `SimpleXMLElement` instances.

## Adding Numbered Elements

To add numbered value elements requires a different approach. You need to iterate from 1 to 3 and add new element nodes with the content from the matching `value` element node. After that is finished you can (optionally) delete the `value` element nodes.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($xml_src);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$maximum = 3;
$regions = $xpath->evaluate('//property[@name = "region"]');
foreach ($regions as $region) {
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $maximum; $i++) {
     $region
       ->appendChild($document->createElement('value'.$i))
       ->appendChild(
         $document->createTextNode(
           $xpath->evaluate('string(value['.$i.'])', $region)
         )
       );
  }
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('value', $region) as $value) {
    $region->removeChild($value);
  }
}

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Comment: Wow! That works great! Thanks! The only thing i stumble upon now is that i need the three value elements to be numbered, see my editted question. I can't find a function to change the elements, is that even possible?

Comment: Why do you need them numbered? This is really bad XML. And would need a complete replacement of all the value nodes. If you need an index you should add it as an attribute like:  `<value index="1"/>`. But even that is redundant information. The `value` nodes have an position inside the parent element. Do you write the import or do you try to match an existing import that does not understand XML?

Comment: Because i use an import plugin that can match unique elements, but fails when the elements have the same name :(

Comment: Added a DOM example for the changed question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to edit existing nodes and it is possible with the lesser known special-purpose, declarative language called [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp) for which PHP maintains an XSL extension to process. As information, XSLT is a recursive template language that can manipulate XML files in any way, shape, or form without any object-oriented coding in its host language (here being PHP).

XSLT isn't as popular as the other special-purpose, declarative language, SQL, but it avoids writing nested loops and manually re-creating every element, attribute, and child.

**XSLT** script (to be saved as .xsl file)

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="//properties">
        <xsl:copy-of select="property[@name='country']"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="property[@name='region']">
            <property name="region">
                <value1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="value[1]"/>
                </value1>
                <value2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="value[2]"/>
                </value2>
                <value3>
                    <xsl:value-of select="value[3]"/>
                </value3>
            </property>
        </xsl:for-each>   
        <xsl:copy-of select="property[position() > 2]"/>       
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP** Script

```
// Set current path
$cd = dirname(__FILE__);

// Load the XML source and XSLT file    
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$xml->load($cd.'/Original.xml');
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load($cd.'/XSLTfile.xsl');

// Transform the original xml
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// Save output to file
$xmlfile = $cd.'/Final.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $newXml);
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated on 09/29/15 at 12:06:15 (http://pf.tradetracker.net) -->
<products>
  <product ID="1">
    <name>Name</name>
    ...
    <property name="country">
      <value>Country</value>
    </property>
    <property name="region">
      <value1>Region info 1</value1>
      <value2>Region info 2</value2>
      <value3>Region info 3</value3>
    </property>
    ...
  </product>
  ...
</products>
```